# What the author is referring to with the word "aquatic ecosystems"

Tags: understanding

River pollution

A team from Cemagref in Lyon (FR) has identified a pertinent indicator of the level of pollution in rivers: the biofilm. A complex combination of bacteria, algae and fungi, the biofilm forms a viscous layer on immersed supports, such as the stones on a river bed. The biofilms are able to break down the pesticides that contaminate aquatic environments and modify their structure, diversity and functioning. Toxic substances, for example, can change the photosynthetic, respiratory or enzymatic activity of aquatic ecosystems, either definitively or temporarily. It is in this way that biofilms can serve as an early warning signal of pollution. It remains to characterize and distinguish the responses of biofilms to pollutants from those induced by environmental factors (current speed, physico-chemical composition, etc.). It is research of this kind that should help respond to the need set out in the Water Framework Directive to improve the ecological quality of European rivers.

I lost the flow of ideas after the sentence "Toxic substances, for example, can change the photosynthetic, respiratory or enzymatic activity of aquatic ecosystems, either definitively or temporarily".

What the author is referring to with the word aquatic ecosystems in the sentence "Toxic substances, for example, can change the photosynthetic, respiratory or enzymatic activity of aquatic ecosystems, either definitively or temporarily".

Comment: In the cited context, both adjectival ***aquatic*** and the noun ***ecosystem*** have their normal meanings as would be defined by ***any*** dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia *aquatic ecosystem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquatic_ecosystem)

> **An aquatic ecosystem is an ecosystem in a body of water.** Communities of organisms that are dependent on each other and on their environment live in aquatic ecosystems. The two main types of aquatic ecosystems are marine ecosystems and freshwater ecosystems.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquatic_ecosystem)

[emphasis added]

A **body of water** is a river, lake or ocean.

[Merriam-Webster *ecosystem*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecosystem)

> 1 : the complex of a community of organisms and its environment functioning as an ecological unit

The M-W has a long paragraph on the word history of "ecosystem".